# React Mapbox GL Js - Animate a camera around a point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I found an example for animating a camera around a point from the official Mapbox GL JS documentation [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-camera-around-point/) but it's written in pure Javascript.

I'm using React Js and [react-map-gl](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl) library and trying to animate the camera around a point like the example above.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import MapGL, {requestAnimationFrame} from 'react-map-gl';

const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 40.67,
    longitude: -103.59,
    zoom: 3,
    bearing: 0,
    pitch: 0
});
const mapRef = useRef(null);

const rotateCamera = (timestamp) => {
    mapRef.rotateTo((timestamp / 100) % 360, { duration: 0 })
    requestAnimationFrame(rotateCamera)
}

useEffect(() => {
    rotateCamera(0)
}, [])

return (
      <MapGL 
        {...viewport}
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        mapStyle={MAP_STYLE}
        onViewportChange={setViewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        ref={mapRef}
      />
);
```

There was a compiled error:

```
Attempted import error: 'requestAnimationFrame' is not exported from 'react-map-gl'.
```

Then I tried to repair the import into:

```js
import MapGL from 'react-map-gl';
import requestAnimationFrame from 'react-map-gl'
```

but there was a runtime error:

```
TypeError: mapRef.rotateTo is not a function
```

Then how do I implement the animate the camera around a point documentation properly?

Comment: you should use your ref like this: mapRef.current.rotateTo(...).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a ref, you should use `mapRef.current`.

To get the mapbox map, you can use `getMap()`.
So you can declare the map as a variable:

`const map = mapRef.current.getMap()` and then call the `rotateTo` function.

Alternatively you can use it directly: `mapRef.current.getMap().rotateTo(args)`